# VueJs Multiselect - only one option showing

Tags: vue.js, multi-select

I'm using VueJS Multiselect and when I make a selection from the drop-down menu the other options disappear. How can I choose multiple options?

Also, how do I remove the [] (square brackets) from displaying at the

You selected: {{ value }}

?

```
  <template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 container">
        <div>
          <Multiselect
            v-model="value"
            :options="posts"
            mode="tags"
            :multiple="true"
            label="title"
          />
        </div>
        <p>You selected: {{ value }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Multiselect from "@vueform/multiselect";

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      posts: [],
      id: [],
      value: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getPosts();
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then((response) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(response);
          this.posts = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style src="@vueform/multiselect/themes/default.css"></style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way **:**

```js
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
    value: {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      },
    posts: [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
        "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 4,
        "title": "eum et est occaecati",
        "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
      }]
  },
  methods: {
    customLabel (option) {
      return option.title
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.3/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.2/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <template>
<multiselect 
             v-model="value" 
             :options="posts"
             :multiple="true"
             track-by="id"
             :custom-label="customLabel"
             >
</multiselect>
<pre>{{ value }}</pre>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really need the data to pull from an Axios request and stick to the <template> format. I cant get this to work with your example.

Comment: This is the same response which you will get from an API. Just for a demo purpose I used mock response Instead of calling an API

Comment: It doesn't work for me in the template format. It errors at '}).$mount('#app')' and still only displays one option. I'm not knowledgeable enough with Vue to fix this.

Comment: It's not a template issue. I added `template` and it is working fine.

Comment: It works okay if i use this as one page and don't pull in the data using Axios. It doesn't work for me when its part of an App and using Axios. Thanks for your time though. I will go away and try and troubleshoot some more.